# Edit page has to be submitted twice for changes to be saved

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have an edit page set up for editing blog posts. Here's the controller action...

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);

    if(!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Post not found');
    }

    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Post updated!');
            $this->redirect('/');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update post!');
        }
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $post;
    }

    $this->set('tags', $this->Post->Tag->find('list'));
    $this->set('pageTitle', 'Edit blog post');
}
```

And the edit pages view...

```
<h1>Edit blog post</h1>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Post.title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Post.body'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Tag.Tag', array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Tags (seperated by space)', 'value' => $tags)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Post.slug'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Save Changes'); ?>
```

For some reason when I make changes and click "save changes", the page just refreshes and although the changes are reflected in the form after the refresh, I have to click "save changes" again for them to get saved to the database and for Cake to redirect me to `/`.

What could be causing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no `Post.id` in your form, CakePHP sends a `PUT` request (instead of a `POST` request) to create (or "put") a new row into your database the first time. This doesn't pass your request check:

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
```

Now, at this point your logic gets the entire row for the corresponding post, with this code:

```
$this->request->data = $post;
```

This will include the ID of the given post, since it's in your `find()` result and hence the second time you submit it, it has an id and therefor sends a `POST` request instead of a `PUT` request.

Assuming you only want to edit **existing** posts, add an `id` field to your form (the FormHelper automagic should make a hidden field of it, but you can always explicitly tell it to, like in the example below):

```
echo $this->Form->input('Post.id', array('type' => 'hidden');
```

This should pass along the id and hence trigger a `POST` request rather than a `PUT` request and make your submission pass at once.

Comment: Really good answer, I understand why now, thanks. However, when I add the post ID to the `edit.ctp` view and try again the page just refreshes when I click save changes. No changes to the database no matter how much I click it.

Comment: @JamesDawson Try to `var_dump` the `$this->request->data` in your view and see if it does have an id in it at all. Otherwise you'll manually need to pass that to your view so Cake knows what ID to update. It sounds like it's empty/unset now.

Comment: Managed to fix it, Cake was sending a `PUT` request instead of `POST` even when given an ID. So I had to do `if($this->request->is('put')) { ... }`. Is this meant to send in `PUT`? It was my understanding that Cake usually does this as `POST`. Anyway, I've accepted your answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: @JamesDawson No, the default action should be `POST`, so I'm not sure why it's going to `PUT` instead. You can also set the `type` attribute explicitly to `POST` when you create the form using `$this->Form->create('Post', array('type' = 'POST'));`.